# Reduce frequency of vector points based on attribute or spacing

Tags: qgis, proximity

I have a point shapefile with 5000+ points.  The points represent centroids of a flood model mesh output and I want to display the flow direction attribute in the form of an "arrow" point style.  I want to display for purposes of printed maps.

The points are too dense to allow practical presentation.  I would have preference for retaining all data, but ultimately I need a way to "thin out" the points so that I only retain points that are outside a proximity to another point and/or is significantly different in the direction attribute to the adjacent points.

How can I achieve this / can I achieve this in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps to thin the points:

1. Install the plugin Concave Hull, which clusters points by their nearest neighbor using a density-based clustering algorithm
2. In Vector> Concave Hull > Concave Hull, select your point layer as the input layer and the adjust the number of neighbors and neighborhood size  parameters accordingly (you should select 'Find SNN clusters')
3. The output shapefile should be a bunch of polygons that represent your clusters.
4. Find the centroids of these polygons using Vector > Geometry Tools > Polygon centroids
5. Use the centroids as your reduced point data

Answer (score 0):

How about completely working around the density issue by using a line instead of the arrow. Make the lines long enough to have some overlap and of course use the QGIS rotationfield. This would quickly give a general impression of the flow directions.